# Colatting data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, view, union

When I am retrieving data from multiple tables in my mySQL database what approach is best to use, joins, unions or view? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each and what circumstances do they suit best?

Comment: There's no one right answer here.  It depends on the data you have and what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: A view can use either JOINs and/or UNIONs, and is potentially less likely to perform as well as against the table(s) directly if predicate pushing can not occur.  But I agree with Joel -- this question is too broad, and should be targeted to specific databases at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really depends on how you want this data to be displayed.

Joins are used for when you want to select data that is related and display it all in the same row, where Unions are used for appeneding data from two different select statements together.

In your case, a view should be used when you have a very complex query, and you want to simplify the select statement that is needed to select the data.  It will make it less confusing if you are going to use the select statement over and over.  There are plenty of other reasons to use views, but I do not think they are relavent to this question.

Comment: Thanks that is the sort of information I am after

Answer (score 0):

What @jworrin said.

SQL is all about set operations.

- `A inner join B` is set intersection: A ∩ B
- `A union B` is ... well ... set union: A ∪ B
- `A left join B` is a composite: ( A ∉ ( A ∩ B ) ) ∪ ( A ∩ B )
- `right join` is the same as a left join. Just syntactic sugar to swap positions of the tables/sets involved. `B right join A` is identical to `A left join B`.
- `A full join B` is also a composite: ( A ∉ ( A ∩ B ) ) ∪ ( A ∩ B ) ∪ ( B ∉ ( A ∩ B ) )

Which you use is entirely dependent on the problem.

A `view` is essentially an invariant, canned select statement. It lets you present "virtual tables", for instance, a de-normalized, flat view of a normalized database. Views are also useful for such things as restricting access to columns and/or tables.